# Record screen using android studio 0.8.x from a device below API Level 19(4.4)?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-4.4-kitkat

Currently I am not able to record my application flow using Android studio DDMS -> Record screen feature below 4.4 API level. The record button seems disabled. Is there any way to use this feature? any other idea to record screen in below 4.4?

As per developer doc "The screenrecord command is a shell utility for recording the display of devices running Android 4.4 (API level 19) and higher."

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to use this feature?

No.

> any other idea to record screen in below 4.4?

Run an emulator and use a desktop screen-capture tool.

Or, use a device that supports HDMI-out and use an HDMI recorder.

Or, root your device and use various software screen recorders available via search engines.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). Let me try.